# Install PostgreSQL server via NPM

Tags: postgresql, npm

Is there any NPM package to install a PostgreSQL server locally?

I want to create a fully isolated and automatic test environment where the server could be installed via NPM, with some basic functions, such as:

- set the server port
- start the server
- stop the server
- set the default/admin user with password

Even if I can get the bare minimum that PostgreSQL server requires in order to run, it would be sufficient, as long as multi-instancing is possible, given different server ports.

Effectively, what I'm looking for is like what NVM is for installing and managing Node.js installations.

Comment: maybe you find something on [turnkey](https://www.turnkeylinux.org/postgresql)